# Git: How to push a subdirectory to a separate branch of the same repository

Tags: git, github

The current project I am working on is limited to one git repository. 
My current working directory looks something like this:

```
dist/
  *distribution files

src/
  *src files
```

We have an Azure server set up to automatically deploy anything pushed to the 'deploy' branch of our repo. So the objective is to push src files to master and the content of the dist folder to the 'deploy' branch.

What I've been doing up until now is branching off master, deleting the src folder, and moving the contents of the dist folder to the root before pushing to deploy.

I know ideally we would have separate repos, but that's not an option currently. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) command works great for this. From your `master` branch do:

```
git subtree split --branch deploy --prefix dist/
```

Just run that command every time you want to update the `deploy` branch. It will merge every commit in the `dist` subdir (of the current branch--presumably `master`) to the root of the `deploy` branch and maintain a full commit history. Note that only changes in the `dist` subdir will be merged. If a commit includes changes both to the `dist` subdir and other files in the repo, only the changes in the `dist` subdir get included.

The tricky part is installation. As I understand it,  the command is included with git 1.7.11 and higher. However, it's in the "contrib" subtree, so it's not installed by default. Search for "git-subtree" in your system's package manager and install the package if it exists. If not, or if you are using an older version of git, the easiest way I've found is to install git-subtree from the author's [repo](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree).

```
git clone https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree.git
cd git-subtree/
make install
```

Once you get it installed, you can do various cool things with it as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks mate.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing, but when the build files or `dist` is in `.gitignore` and kept out of master? To clarify, I want only dist files in the deploy branch, and want only src files in the master.

Comment: @Lawren i have the same case because `dist` is in `.gitignore`, did you got the solution for that?

Comment: Two years later I have the same need. Did you figure it out?

Comment: This question is about a subdirectory of the git repo, not a directory which is excluded from the git repo. If the directory you want to use as a source is in `.gitignore`, then this won't work for you. In fact, that would be a completely different question than the one asked here.